# Measuring the dampening sinusoidal wave of a simple LC Tank circuit?

Tags: oscillator, oscilloscope, wave

I've been trying to do the simplest of things...measure the decaying sinusoidal wave of a LC Tank circuit on a breadboard.

I've created an "inductor" out of a coil of copper wire I wrapped around a pen. I have a 1uF capacitor connected in parallel with this "inductor."

I charge the capacitor with a 9V battery, then remove the positive lead which should produce a sin wave.

I have the ground of my o-scope connected to one lead of the capacitor, and the positive lead attached to the other lead of the capacitor.

On the o-scope (analog, mind you)  I just see what looks like the capacitor discharging its current over time. (I.E. I see 9v steadily decreasing to 0v.)

What could I possibly be doing wrong with such a simple circuit?

Comment: Not enough inductance, too much resistance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1) Set the scope to single-sweep at a trigger level of about half of your supply voltage.

2) Connect one end of the capacitor, one end of the inductor, the scope ground, and the power supply ground together.

3) Connect the scope probe hot to the other end of the inductor, but let the cap float.

4) Arm the scope.

5) Momentarily connect supply hot to the floating end of the cap in order to charge it.

6) Disconnect the supply from the cap and, while watching the scope screen, touch the floating end of the cap to the end of the coil connected to the scope probe.

7) You should see the damped oscillation.

If you don't, make sure that your scope is triggering properly, that you've got the sweep speed and amplitude settings right, and that you've got the brightness cranked high enough to let you see a single sweep.

Just for grins, here's a link to an [LTspice simulation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3jn14mr9q16jux6/RLC%20resonance.asc?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the coil is disconnected and you are observing the capacitor discharging in the scope. If the coil was connected in parallel with the capacitor, it would effectively short the 9V battery during the "charge the capacitor" step of the experiment

Even with proper wiring, the energy stored in the coil would vanish so quickly that an analog scope would have trouble capturing that. Analog scopes are good for repetitive events, not single-shot.

Comment: This is why I used a 1uF cap.